# How to use array to overwrite string in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace, overwrite

So I have a bunch of languages that $langTo outputs, i.e. 'de' or 'cn'. When I echo them I don't want them to be displayed as **de** but as **German**, and **cn** as **Chinese**.

```
$langTo = $_SESSION['langTo']; // outputs the spoken language in 'de'

$array = array(
    "de" => "German",
    "cn" => "Chinese",
);

<?php echo $langTo; ?>
```

What is the correct way to replace a list of strings? Or should I use **str_replace**?

Comment: `echo $array[$langTo];`

Comment: @Rizier123 Thanks, I totally overlooked that it could be solved like this. I was thinking of if statements etc. lol. I'm learning please bare with me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'cn' or 'de' is the key of your array. In PHP, it called [associative array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). You don't want to replace them to display what its value.

```
echo $array['cn'];
```

will get the value 'Chinese'.

So if you want to echo what $langTo is represent. you can use `$array[$langTo]`